# Failure of aws sync: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to use the aws cli to sync files from my machine to s3. Should be simple enough, right?

Here is what is happening:

```
$ aws s3 sync mydir/ s3://mybucket --profile me
'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'read'
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

I know that there are no permissions issues, as the same command (with `--recursive`) works if `cp` is used in place of `sync`. I've experimented with adding `--recursive`, with `--dryrun`, and with using or not using the trailing slashes, but no change.

I'm on OS X, if that matters, and the system python is version 2.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a bug.

Upgrade:

```
$ sudo pip install -U awscli
```

This moved me from version 1.6.3 to 1.6.4, and now this problem doesn't exist.